# Three part discount in java

Tags: java

so I need to make a calculator that calculates discounts with the total. I have no idea what I am missing that my code is not running, I need it to read the amount entered and assign the correct discount ( 100 or less 5%, more than 100 less than 250 10%, 250 or more 15%) then produce the total amount after discount and tax
Thank you for any help or advice =)

```
/*
    Sarah Goldberg Week 5 3 part discount 
*/
import java.util.*;

public class Discount5 {

    public static final double TAXRATE = 0.06; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double amount, tax, subTotal, due;
        final double discount;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Total due calculation program");

        //input 
        System.out.print("Enter the sales amount: $");
        amount = input.nextDouble();

        //discount
        if (amount <= 100){
            discount = amount * 0.05;
        }
        else if (amount > 250 & amount < 100) {
            discount = amount * 0.10; 
        }
        else (amount >= 250) {
            discount = amount * 0.15;
        }

        subTotal = amount - discount;


        tax = subTotal * TAXRATE;


        due = subTotal + tax;

        // output 
        System.out.println("Bill Summary:");
        System.out.printf("   sales amount: $%2.2f\n", amount);
        System.out.printf("   discount: $%2.2f\n", discount);
        System.out.printf("   tax (at  %2.2f%%): $%2.2f\n",(TAXRATE*100),tax);
        System.out.printf("  Total due: $%2.2f\n" ,due);

        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: your else if is reversed. It should be > 100 && < 250

Answer (score 2):

Your && operator is wrong and you should not write any condition in else.

```
if (amount <= 100){
        discount = amount * 0.05;
    }
    else if (amount < 250 && amount > 100) {
        discount = amount * 0.10; 
    }
    else {
        discount = amount * 0.15;
    }
```

You can't use discount as a `final` variable if your discount is changing in if-else block and it wasn't initialized too, you need to initialize it too.

This will work -

```
/*
    Sarah Goldberg Week 5 3 part discount 
*/
import java.util.*;

public class Discount5 {

public static final double TAXRATE = 0.06; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double amount, tax, subTotal, due;
    double discount = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Total due calculation program");

    //input 
    System.out.print("Enter the sales amount: $");
    amount = input.nextDouble();

    //discount
    if (amount <= 100){
        discount = amount * 0.05;
    }
    else if (amount < 250 && amount > 100) {
        discount = amount * 0.10; 
    }
    else if(amount>=250) {
        discount = amount * 0.15;
    }

    subTotal = amount - discount;


    tax = subTotal * TAXRATE;


    due = subTotal + tax;

    // output 
    System.out.println("Bill Summary:");
    System.out.printf("   sales amount: $%2.2f\n", amount);
    System.out.printf("   discount: $%2.2f\n", discount);
    System.out.printf("   tax (at  %2.2f%%): $%2.2f\n",(TAXRATE*100),tax);
    System.out.printf("  Total due: $%2.2f\n" ,due);

    input.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Oh my god im a dummy, duh...... however I am still getting an error on my else if statement.

Comment: Try the new one because I'm getting the result.

Comment: @SarahGoldberg This answer should get you desired result. Apart from && operator you have `else (amount >= 250)`  replace this with `else`

Comment: You can help me by upvoting and accepting my answer XD

Answer (score 1):

&& operator is wrong

```
else if (amount > 100 && amount < 250 ) {
    discount = amount * 0.10; 
}
```

and discount should not be final

Comment: I changed all that around and this is the error Eclipse is giving me,  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
 The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
 Syntax error on token "<", delete this token
 Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression
 Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

 at Week5.main(Week5.java:25)